# How to search date from two datepicker in database sql wpf c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datepicker

I want to search date and month from two datepickers but it shows all dates and months in database.

How to fix it?

In database for date I use field type `varchar[15]`.

Code:

```
if (Searchbox.Text == "")
{
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM checkwork WHERE checkDate BETWEEN ('" + datePick1.Text + "') AND ('" + datePick2.Text + "')", con);
    adapter.Fill(ds1);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    con.Close();
}
```

It shows all dates and months but I want to show date and month on assign.
[image]

Comment: The usual string format of a date in MySQL is '2017-02-26 14:01:02'. So, you will need to use NSDateFormatter to get the date picker value in the correct format. Storing it as a string as you are won't select well, especially without a leading zero on the day and month.

Comment: This is not how you pass parameters to a [table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx) adapter. You will have a risk of sql injection. Your field needs to be of type date and not string as well.